# Dynamically add form elements in MDL

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I want to add a text input element to a form dynamically. I'm using mdl for css3 framework. I am addin the new elemnt to this form:

```
    <form>
  <div id="enter-participant-details-div">
    <div id="1" class="mdl-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell--6-col">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="participant[]" required />
       <label class="mdl-textfield__label">Participant 1</label>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I add the new text element by using :

```
var x = '<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-js-textfield mdl-cell--6-col" style="margin:2px;" >'
      +'  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="participant[]" required />'
      +'  <label class="mdl-textfield__label">Participant 2</label>'
    +'</div>';
$('#enter-participant-details-div').append(x);
```

When I try to do that, the css properties of the new text input is not changing.

check at => https://jsfiddle.net/mr4pswaq/2/

what should I do to make it look like the first text input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, you would need to manually upgrade it.

Just add the following line:

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Comment: I was trying to fix it for about 5 hours wasting all the time. Thanks so much. It really worked.